# How to Use Auth() Register During Login Session in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authorization, laravel-authentication, laravel-session

I have changed the register page of Laravel 5.7 Auth() to the studentRegister page to register a new student, but it is inaccessible when I'm logged in through another user. The route didn't work while I'm in the session. However, it works perfectly after logging out from one session.

Please suggest how I can register a new student while I'm logged in.

**studentRegister.blade.php**

I have removed {{csrf}} as well.

```php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('registerStudent') }}">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name" type="text"
                                           class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                           name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email"
                                       class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email"
                                           class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                           name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password"
                                       class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password"
                                           class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                                           name="password" required>
                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password-confirm"
                                       class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control"
                                           name="password_confirmation" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <input id="role_id" type="hidden" name="role_id" value="1">

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Register') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, am I right in guessing you want to implement a user account that can create additional student accounts?  Do both account types use the same table structure?

Comment: yes exactly I m having only one user table !!! now after removing $this->middleware('guest'); whenever I register student by other page  after getting logged in after registering it changes the logged user to new created one.

Comment: I see, maybe you need to implement a separate guard and run the student users thought a different controller. I did something similar where managers could create staff accounts but they both had a different table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove this line from your RegisterController __construct :

```
$this->middleware('guest');
```

---

**update**
You can also define new registration.
You can define new route :

```
Route::get('register2', 'yourController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register2');
Route::post('register2', 'yourController@register');
```

And in yourController :

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('auth.register2');
}

public function register(Request $req)
{
    $req->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
    ]);

    User::create([
        'name' => $req->name,
        'email' => $req->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($req->password),
    ]);
    return 'something';
}
```

And copy/paste/rename your register blade to register2 and just change the form action to `{{ route('register2') }}`

Comment: Thanks @behnam but this worked for opening page at that session but it changes the session of current user to new created user, it automatically gets new user logged in without getting old user logged out.

Comment: Yes, I suggest you don't change the default pages and use another way. I edit my answer. Hope to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

go to studentRegisterController.php and 
delete this function

```
 public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest');
        }
```

and if you use the default Register
go to app/Http/Controller/Auth/RegisterController.php
and delete this line

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @layouteam but
this worked for opening page at that session but it changes the session of current user to new created user, it automatically gets new user logged in without getting old user logged out.